# Css transitions aren't working properly in chrome/opera on a specific computer.

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, css-transitions, opera

I'm currently working with css transitions and they're working perfectly on two other computers, however, on my main computer the transitions will not appear or are extremely choppy in Chrome and Opera. I've tried re-installing Chrome but the problem still persists. The transitions do appear and work perfectly in Firefox, Internet Explorer & Safari. Like I said, the transitions are working for Chrome on my other computers. Another thing I've also noticed is my :hover is not working either.

I've inspected my code with web developer tools and have noticed that the code is applied immediately, but the transitions are not present and the actual switch takes way longer than the duration time.

Css transitions and transitions applied with JavaScript both do not work:

JavaScript:

```
function slider_ease()
{
    slider_images.style.transition = 'all 1s ease';
    slider_images.style.MozTransition = 'all 1s ease';
    slider_images.style.WebkitTransition = 'all 1s ease';
}
```

CSS:

```
.slider_button
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
    transition: all.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all.3s ease;
}
```